# Requiring unknow module - XHRInterceptor

Tags: android, react-native

I got requiring unknown module error when i'm running react native android application. Earlier it works normally.I tried cleaning npm cache and removing node module directory as well. Still I couldn't fix it. How can I fix this?

node version: v6.2.1
npm version: 3.9.3
compileSdkVersion: 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

[image: test]